# I can't use React Context API with NavigationContainer in React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-context

I want to create a context which will wrap all my screens, so i can use navigationContainer theme prop to add dark or light mode to my components.
the way i found to solve this was wrapping everything in a ReactContext, so i would toggle the dark state wherever i want.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzqzY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLaDd.png)

Here is my code

```
const ClientTabNavigator = () => {

    const theme = useTheme();
    const {setInitialState} = useContext(ThemeContext);
    const toggleTheme = () => setInitialState(prevState => ({...prevState, dark:!prevState.dark}))

    const screenOptions = {
        title:'',
        headerLeft:() => (<View style={{marginLeft:20}}>
            <Pressable onPress={toggleTheme}>
                <Ionicons name="moon" {...HeaderIconStyle({theme})}/>
            </Pressable>
        </View>),
    }

        
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={screenOptions}>
            <Tab.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1}/>
            <Tab.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2}/>
            <Tab.Screen name="Screen3" component={Screen3}/>
            <Tab.Screen name="Screen4" component={Screen4}/>
        </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}

export default ClientTabNavigator
```

My App

```
const LightTheme = {
    dark:false,
    colors:{
        background:Colors.theme.white,
        text:Colors.theme.grey_500,
        card:Colors.theme.grey_100,
        navIcon:Colors.theme.grey_500,
    }
}
const DarkTheme = {
    dark:true,
    colors:{
        background:Colors.theme.grey_600,
        text:Colors.theme.grey_400,
        card:Colors.theme.grey_700,
        navIcon:Colors.theme.grey_200,
    }
}

export const ThemeContext = createContext({dark:false})

const App = () => {

    const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState({dark:false});


    return (
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={{initialState, setInitialState}}>
            <NavigationContainer theme={initialState.dark ? DarkTheme : LightTheme} >
                    <TabNavigator.ClientTabNavigator/>
            </NavigationContainer>
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

i appreciate any help

i tried to wrap NavigationContainer into React Context so i can change dark from initialState every where